# not sending messages from script

Tags: php, serial-port, at-command

I know i might gonna so many down vote but please help me through this as i nearly there. I have below code.

```
<?php
exec("mode COM1 BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off");
$fp = fopen ("\\.\com1", "r+");
//$fp = dio_open('COM5:', O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
if (!$fp) 
{
    echo "Uh-oh. Port not opened.";
} 
else 
{

    $string  = "AT+CMGF=1";

    $string  = $string."OK";

    $string  = $string."AT+CMGS='+44XXXXX'";

    $string  = $string."> Hello World?<Ctrl>+<Z>";

    $string  = $string."+CMGS: 44";

    $string  = $string."OK";

    fputs ($fp, $string );
    echo $string."\n";
    fclose ($fp);
}

?>
```

above code is outputting `AT+CMGF=1OKAT+CMGS='+44XXXX'> Hello World?++CMGS: 44OK` but not actually sending any message to that number.

I have device is attached with PC which has SIM card in it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

From what I know of AT commands, is that it is a dialogue. You have to send `AT+CMGF=1` then wait for the **modem to send** `OK`, send the next command etcetera.

You are now sending everything, including the modem's responses in one string.

More information (as always) on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

The code should be along the lines of (off the top of my head, not tested):

```
$string = "AT+CMGF=1";
fputs($fp, $string);
$r = fgets($fp);
if ($r == "OK") {
  $string = "AT+CMGS='+44XXXXX'";
  fputs($fp, $string);
  $r = $fgets($fp);
  ... etc ...
}
```

Comment: Thanx for reply i read somewhere that i need to use sleep command for few sec to AT command to response...is that right..???and how can i test it in terminal.?

Comment: I'd use a blocking read. Note that I just used `fgets` to explain how to do it. You will have to figure out timing and formatting yourself (it greatly depends on the modem and connection). With [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php) you can set `fgets` to blocking.

Comment: Okay i am come so far now and just wanted know why php not executing `AT+CMGS` do i need to include any extension.?

Comment: Big change you modem is not responding. Try to figure out its behaviour first with a tool like `minicom` or HyperTerm.

Comment: In addition, consider using SMS services that let you send messages through an HTTP API for a small fee.

Comment: Bart is right - you should enter this sequence of AT commands manually in HyperTerminal or minicom before you try to program it. Observe the response to each command. Then you'll understand how the modem really behaves.